# Keeping or not keeping header in the CSV for training

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

Is it always required to remove the header from an imported CSV for training?

This is what I have...

```
raw_data_df = [pd.read_csv(
            file, header=None, skiprows=[0], low_memory=False) for file in input_files]
train_data_df = pd.concat(raw_data_df)
```

We used `header=None` and `skiprows=[0]` when skipping the header, and we pass it to  `LogisticRegression().fit()`

Or is it better for keeping the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the headers in all files are all equal, then you can keep them. Or you only keep the header of the first file.

The advantage of having a header is that when you run the logistic regression, you can easily find out which coefficients belong to which column names (and so which coefficients are most important).

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

df_lr_coef = pd.DataFrame({
    'features': lr.classes_, 
    'coefficients': lr.coef_,
    'coef_abs': np.abs(lr.coef_),
}).sort_values(by='coef_abs', ascending=False)
```

Comment: Keeping the headers should not affect the model's performance or create unnecessary noises right?

Comment: no, not that i know of. it's for good reason that sklearn accepts dataframes as input, it allows for easier model inspection. For speeding up training, set n_jobs=-1